# First Parameter isn't being passed using Ajax and MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I don't know what i may be doing wrong here but can you guyz spot anything that i maybe missing?  So as below i have got a Method in my controller that is receiving 2 parameters from an Ajax call . The first parameter isn't being passed for some reason and is always returned as null i'm not sure why this is. On the other hand the second parameter is being passed to my method in the controller

```
public ActionResult TurboVehicle( int? manId, decimal? engine)
{
    var partnumber = _catalogue.Data.Where(x => x.man_ID == manId && x.Engine == engine)
      .Select(x => x.TurboType).FirstOrDefault();
    return PartialView("_vehicle", model);
}
```

Ajax call

```
var manId = $("#SelectedVehicle").val();
var engine = $("#SelectedEngine").val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: '../../Vehicles/TurboVehicle',                   
    data: { manId: manId, engine: engine },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {                     
        console.log(vehId); //the value does print here
    }
});
```

I also tried to change the url to the following:

```
url: '../../Vehicles/TurboVehicle/' + manId + '/' + engine
```

Still i get the same thing.  Is there anything that I may be doing wrong in the above context?

Comment: Either replace `vehId` with `manId` in jquery or `manId` with `vehId` in action method.

Comment: sorry see edit.. i forgot to change that ! but even when i set the property names the same .. i get the same result

Comment: Can you `console.log(manId)` and confirm it has a value? Any reason why the dataType is 'html' and not 'json'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property names should be same
change "vehId" to "manId"

Comment: sorry see edit.. i forgot to change that ! but even when i set the property names the same .. i get the same resu

Comment: That script can be cached. Try to restart your server and browser to make sure new script is running.